# Is API Gateway Default Method Throttling per all requests or per client?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

For a stage belonging to an API in AWS API Gateway I have the option to limit Default Method Throttling. Does this limit the *total number of requests* per second, or the number of requests *from a particular client* per second?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default Method **Throttling** (like Account Level Throttling) is the total number of requests per second across *everyone* hitting your API.

Client-level limits are enforced with **Usage Plans**, based on api-keys.

For more detailed information about API Gateway throttling checkout:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-request-throttling.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html

Comment: I found the formulation in the aws-docu very misleading:
"Throttling and quota **limits apply to requests for individual API keys** that are aggregated across all API stages within a usage plan".

In reality the limits are **shared across all API-keys within a usage plan**.
Double confirmed that with AWS support.

Comment: @Skip that isn't correct. The limits aren't shared by all api keys within a usage plan. They are shared across apis per usage plan + api key combination.

Comment: @theawless have I understood you correctly: when creating a usage plan, and assigning an API X to usage-plan, and creating 2 api-keys K1, K2   THEN when **calling API X with K1** would give me independent throttling counter, of when **calling API X with K2**

Comment: Yes that's correct, keys always get different counters.

With your example if you create API Y and attach it to the usage plan as well, then "are aggregated across all API stages within a usage plan" would mean calling API X with K1 and API Y with K1 would get a shared counter, but API X with K1 and API X with K2 will get different counters.